# Can't get attribute 'style' of element

Tags: c#, css

I'm using c# to get HtmlElement and its attrubutes, but can't get the 'style' attrubute. 
In some previous posts here one suggested soultion kept coming on: use the 'style' or the 'cssText' properties to do so. Only it doesn't work for me since VS says it "cannot resolve those symbols".
I tried this code:

```
        HtmlElementCollection elements = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
        {
            var temp = elements[i].GetAttribute('style').cssText;
        }
```

And also this one:

```
        HtmlElementCollection elements = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
        {
            var temp = elements[i].style.cssText;
        }
```

The "regular" aproache - to use GetAttrubure method doesn't do the job either, since it returns an object of type "System.__ComObject".

Does anyone have an idea? 
TNX all

Comment: Why don't you use jquery/javascript??

Comment: @Richa this is not asp.net related, `GetAttribute` is under `System.Windows.Forms`.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As soon as it comes to working with HTML from C# I strongly recommend to use HTML Agility Pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: So, you are trying to do it on server side (C#)? if so, why?